# Rainbow Style Loading Cursor On MacBook Air 2017

Tags: cursor

Is It Normal To Get The Rainbow Colour Loading Cursor Sometimes While Using Safari On The MacBook Air 2017 i5 5th Gen. I'm A First Time Mac User. Sorry If It's Silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sometimes you will see that. The rainbow pinwheel means that an app is busy. Usually it will go away after a few seconds. If it doesn’t, there may be an issue, such as an app, or in some cases, the OS being locked up.

---

Also, since you are new to macOS, you might find this iBook helpful. It is a guide to MacBook written by Apple.
https://books.apple.com/us/book/macbook-air-essentials/id963295730

Comment: It Does Go Away After A Few Seconds. Thanks A Lot. Appreciate It